# How to remove all OverlayEntry from OverlayState at once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm adding an `OverlayEntry` to an `OverlayState` like this

```
var entry1 = OverlayEntry(builder: (_) => FlutterLogo());
var entry2 = OverlayEntry(builder: (_) => FlutterLogo());
var state = Overlay.of(context);

state.insertAll([entry1, entry2]);
```

This works and if I want to remove that added entry I can call remove on it like:

```
entry1.remove();
```

But what if I want to remove all the entries which are currently displayed in `OverlayState`, is there any method like

```
state.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no direct way. However, by just adding 1 extra line can solve the problem and it is the creation of `List<OverlayEntry>`

```
// create a List
var entries = [entry1, entry2];
state.insertAll(entries);
```

And

```
// use this to delete all entries
entries.forEach((entry) => entry.remove());
```